# If range includes date during 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro, and I want to execute some code if a range includes any dates in 2016 (for example). I have a start (I think).

```
Dim rptDateColumn As Range
Set rptDateColumn = Sheets("Data").Range("N:N")
For Each cell In rngRptgDate
    If ... (the date is during 2016)... Then
...This other stuff happens
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract Year from Date Using VBA in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737099/extract-year-from-date-using-vba-in-excel)

Comment: Are you trying to find out if **any** cell in column N is a number between 42370 (1 Jan 2016) and 42735 (31 Dec 2016)?  Or whether **each** cell is in the range?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

`If Year(cell) = 2016 Then`

Comment: Did this fix your issue Lindsay?